# Fine A Precentage(%) Similarity Index Between Two Images in Matlab/Python

Tags: python, image, matlab, similarity, ssim

I am trying to analyse two images: The origional and an approximated version generated using Fourier transforms.

Example:

Original:
[image]

Approx:

[image]

How can i find a value that represents the similarity between these two images. I have tried using SSIM in Matlab, but that gives a value of 0.67, which i personally think is inaccurate.

```
ref = imread('download (1).png');

A = imread('download.png')


subplot(1,2,1); imshow(ref); title('Reference Image');
subplot(1,2,2); imshow(A);   title('Blurred Image');

Calculate the global SSIM value for the image and local SSIM values for each pixel. Return the global SSIM value and display the local SSIM value map.
[ssimval, ssimmap] = ssim(A,ref);

fprintf('The SSIM value is %0.4f.\n',ssimval);

figure, imshow(ssimmap,[]);
title(sprintf('ssim Index Map - Mean ssim Value is %0.4f',ssimval));
```

[image]

Like wise, a few online tools such as this one: https://deepai.org/machine-learning-model/image-similarity Gives a distance value of 6. (0 being the best)

Comment: whats the problem you are facing?

Comment: i am currently trying to use IMATEST software to compute the SSIM, but i keep getting an error when importing my photos. Regarding the matlab results: does this look accurate?

Comment: write IMATEST in tags along with python in stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMATEST software has been updated, fixing this bug.